# Subsurf modifier messing up geometry

Tags: modifiers

I've been using Blender for less than a week, so please have mercy ;)

I'm trying to model this simple weigh boat.

[image: simple weigh boat]

I started with a plane and a circle, solidified the plane, added inset and edge loop, and then created new faces connecting all 16 vertices of the circle to various vertices of the square- each face has 3 or 4 edges. 
[image: Weigh boat without subsurf]
[image: weigh boat without subsurf, edges visible]

The problem is that when I turn on the Subdivision Surface modifier, my square object is converted into higher-order geometry (octagon, etc.).

[image: Weigh boat with subsurf view 1]

How do I smooth the low-poly construct without changing the number of edges? I have a feeling this would involve edge loops but I can't figure out where to put them.

Comment: Your topology for the bubble part (in particular the large many sided shape in the middle, and the long triangles connecting it) is also causing weird subdivision. It would be advisable to split this into quads.